# Disable automatic backup on Excel VSTO 2010 project (C#)

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, backup, vsto

I'm having a trouble.

When I launch my VSTO project and I want to save it, it automatically creates a backup file "**.xlk**".

I have found a way to disable it manually by unchecking backup copy under : **SaveAs -> Tools -> General Options**

But I'd like to find a programmatic way to uncheck the backup file generation (C# VSTO 2010 project)

Iv'e already asked on msdn but the only answer I've had until now is : set CreateBackup property to false but on **vsto workbook projects in Visual Studio 2010** this property is only a getter... here is the link : [msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d5f7d57d-6317-448a-bdd1-d56478746dce/disable-automatic-backup-on-excel-vsto-project?forum=vsto&prof=required)
And I want to avoid the VBA solution which consists in disabling it by macros.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi,

I have noticed that when I want to save the document in a shared foder it automatically creates the xlk backup file. And if I save it on my hard drive it doesn't create it... I really don't understand this phenomenon... Is it a security auto activation or something like this ?



Many thanks,

Comment: Nobody knows about this situation ?